# Prolog | Access to element on list

Tags: prolog

I have this code on .pl file, and i want search a list with length = 1 and return the element inside. This code it's giving me an error. I don't know how do it exactly. can someone give me some advice? I'm new on prolog.

In this case it should return ccc

```
list([aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]).
list([aaa, ccc, ddd]).
list([aaa, ccc]).
list([ccc]).

search_list(Element) :- list(A), length(A, Size), Size is 1.
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the syntax of Prolog, but my length is misspelled in your code.

Comment: @Tyberius: it would be nice if there was a bot that searched for `lenght` and other common typos of `lenght`, since this happens often, and every now and then, that is even the reason why it is not working :).

Comment: Yes sorry, i already correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with unification:

```
search_list(Element) :-
    list([Element]).  % ← unification with a singleton list
```

This will thus only unify `Element` with `ccc`, since the other lists are not singleton lists.

For a list with an arbitrary number of elements, you can make use of the [**`member/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) predicate:

```
search_list(Element) :-
    list(List),
    member(Element, List).  % ← unify with elements of List
```